# Using PHP DOM to extract a certain node value, only if another node value is > 0

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am using php dom to parse xml from another platform, extract certain data from it, and upload to my own platform. I am however stuck when it comes to extracting a certain node value, only if another node value is greater than 0 for the child node 'row'. In the example below, I would like to iterate over the xml and pull out the 'affcustomid' value only if the CPACommission node value is greater than 0. Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this? The below code is a shortened version, in reality, i would get back 100's of rows in the same format as below.

```
<row>
<rowid>1</rowid>
<currencysymbol>&#8364;</currencysymbol>
<totalrecords>2145</totalrecords>
<affcustomid>11159_4498302</affcustomid>
<period>7/1/2014</period>
<impressions>0</impressions>
<clicks>1</clicks>
<clickthroughratio>0</clickthroughratio>
<downloads>1</downloads>
<downloadratio>1</downloadratio>
<newaccountratio>1</newaccountratio>
<newdepositingacc>1</newdepositingacc>
<newaccounts>1</newaccounts>
<firstdepositcount>1</firstdepositcount>
<activeaccounts>1</activeaccounts>
<activedays>1</activedays>
<newpurchases>12.4948</newpurchases>
<purchaccountcount>1</purchaccountcount>
<wageraccountcount>1</wageraccountcount>
<avgactivedays>1</avgactivedays>
<netrevenueplayer>11.8701</netrevenueplayer>
<Deposits>12.4948</Deposits>
<Bonus>0</Bonus>
<NetRevenue>11.8701</NetRevenue>
<TotalBetsHands>4</TotalBetsHands>
<Product1Bets>4</Product1Bets>
<Product1NetRevenue>11.8701</Product1NetRevenue>
<Product1Commission>30</Product1Commission>
<Commission>0</Commission>
<CPACommission>30</CPACommission>
</row>
```

Thanks in advance!
Mark

Comment: do post you code for searching through the *nodes*.

Comment: Hi sunbabaphu, I'm sad to say I don't actually have any right now, what I have tried has failed miserably, i am very new to PHP and using DOM so please forgive me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier using SimpleXML:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
foreach ($doc->row AS $row) { 
    if($row->CPACommission > 0){
        echo $row->affcustomid;
    }
}
```

But if you still need  to use DOMDocument:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('file.xml');
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('row') AS $row) { 
    if($row->getElementsByTagName('CPACommission')->item(0)->textContent > 0){
        echo $row->getElementsByTagName('affcustomid')->item(0)->textContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply smistry but trying that code out, all i seem to get is a blank page? I am looking to actually loop through the whole xml doc so i presume using ->item(0) in your above dom example would not work anyway?

Comment: If you had a doc full of rows then You would loop through each row : `foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('row') AS $row) { }` (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks Smistry appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fetch data from an XML DOM is Xpath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('file.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//row[CPACommission > 0]/affcustomid)')
);
```